# Call DB2 stored procedure from SQL Server 2008 linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, db2

I have a linked server from SQL Server 2008 to DB2. The linked server uses the IBM Drivers and not the Microsoft ones.

So this works from SQL Server:

```
exec ('call RERTEBT.GET_DEFINITION (69,'''','''')') AT MyLinkedDB2Server
```

This also works using openQuery... which is returning different data from another table

```
select
RPMG_ETY_CD,
     ROW_CU_DATA_IN,
ROW_EF_DT,
ROW_XPR_DT,
RPMG_ETY_NM
from 
OPENQUERY 
         (MyLinkedDB2Server,
                'select 
                      RPMG_ETY_CD,
                      ROW_CU_DATA_IN,
                      ROW_EF_DT,
                      ROW_XPR_DT,
                      RPMG_ETY_NM
                 from RERTEBT.V1RERRMM')
```

However I cannot get a select to return data with the DB2 Sproc

This fails -

```
SELECT FLT_DFN_ID, FLT_SRC_DFN_NO, FLT_VRSN_NO, FLT_STAT_CD, FLT_TY_CD, FLT_NAME 
      FROM OPENQUERY (MyLinkedDB2Server, 
                         'call RERTEBT.GET_DEFINITION 69,'''','''')')
```

Has anyone any idea on how to call a DB2 stored procedure from SQL Server Linked server and return the data or can this be done. I read somewhere the DB2 cant do this but haven't seen any real documentation on it.

Thanks D

Comment: anyone any ideas please ? thnks

Answer (score 5):

More explanation for Josef's answer:
  You need to right-click the linked server's "**properties**"
  then -> "**Server option**"
  The "**RPC**" and "**RPC Out**" option in the right pane need to be **TRUE**

-- edited -- I can't comment on the answer yet (don't have 50 rep)

Answer (score 3):

Your should be able to do this:

```
EXEC ('{CALL RERTEBT.GET_DEFINITION (69,'''','''')}') AT MyLinkedDB2Server;
```

Or even cleaner with passing variables

```
EXEC ('{CALL RERTEBT.GET_DEFINITION (?,?,?)}', 69, '', '') AT MyLinkedDB2Server;
```

Comment: This worked after making the server setting change described above by @gonatee.  Thank you.